# Bukkit - NPE using VaultAPI (Chat)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit, bukkit-vault

When trying to set the player suffix/prefix from the GUI I am getting a null pointer exception for setting the said prefix/suffix. (I get the 'You applied the x tag' message, and it does close the inventory.)

Main class (Where the chat is defined and setup, not the entire class)

```
public static Chat chat = null;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private TagsCommands tCmd;

public void onEnable() {
    if (Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") != null) {
        setupChat();
        createFolders();
        Message.console("&fPlugin successfully loaded");
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new TagsGUI(), this);
        tCmd = new TagsCommands(this);
    } else {
        Message.console("&dCouldn't enable plugin as &aVault&c was not found");
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
        return;
    }
}

private boolean setupChat() {
    RegisteredServiceProvider<Chat> chatProvider = getServer().getServicesManager()
            .getRegistration(net.milkbowl.vault.chat.Chat.class);
    if (chatProvider != null) {
        chat = chatProvider.getProvider();

    }
    return (chat != null);
}
```

GUI class (Again, not the entire thing. The error lies in this class at line 55.)

```
@EventHandler
public void inventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    ItemStack click = event.getCurrentItem();
    if (opened.contains(player)) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        File tags = new File("plugins/Tags/Pages", "One.yml");
        FileConfiguration tagsC = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(tags);
        for (String title : tagsC.getConfigurationSection("Tags").getKeys(false)) {
            String tag = tagsC.getString("Tags." + title + ".Display");
            if (click.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(Format.color(tag))) {
                if (player.hasPermission(tagsC.getString("Tags." + title + ".Permission"))) {
                    if (tagsC.getString("Tags." + title + ".Type").equalsIgnoreCase("prefix")) {
                        player.closeInventory();
                        Message.player("&fYou applied the '" + tag + "&f' tag", player);
                        Main.chat.setPlayerPrefix(player, Format.color(tag));
                        break;
                    } else if (tagsC.getString("Tags." + title + ".Type").equalsIgnoreCase("suffix")) {
                        player.closeInventory();
                        Message.player("&fYou applied the '" + tag + "&f' tag", player);
                        Main.chat.setPlayerSuffix(player, Format.color(tag));
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    Message.player("&fSorry, but you do not have permission to do this", player);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Line 55: 
Main.chat.setPlayerSuffix(player, Format.color(tag));

Console error message:

```
[11:13:05 INFO]: BearToothh issued server command: /tags
[11:13:12 ERROR]: Could not pass event InventoryClickEvent to Tags v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:500) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:485) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1889) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:33) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:10) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:748) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:406) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:679) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:577) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.askingg.tags.TagsGUI.inventoryClick(TagsGUI.java:55) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-2b93d83]
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static Chat chat = null;` is `null` so it returns a NullPointerException.
You cannot define a chat thats null and set prefixes and stuff on a chat that dont exist ^^
You have to define the `Chat chat` variable to an existing chat.